# Symfony - delete by ID

Tags: php, symfony

I defined mu delete function to delete row by ID but everytime i try something new I get an error so I doubt that my logic is right.

this is my controller and service

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $query = $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('du')
        ->delete('du')
        ->where('du.id = :id')
        ->setParameter("id", $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    return $query;
}

/**
 * @param $id
 * @Route("/users/delete/{id}", name="user_delete")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
 */
public function getUserDeleteAction($id)
{

    $this->get('user')->deleteUser($id);

    return $this->success();
}
```

Comment: `I get an error`. you get _what_ error? (errormessage and/or stacktrace would be helpful)

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'du WHERE du.id': Error: Class 'du' is not defined. @Fabian Schöner

Comment: What does $this->getUserRepository() return?

Comment: This: public function getUserRepository()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
    } @ Vyctorya

Comment: And I also get Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

Answer (score 1):

You should use ->remove() in the controller.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $em->getRepository(‘...’)->findOneBy([‘id’ => $id]);
//or, $user = $em->find(EntityName::class, $id);
$em->remove($user);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: also - as id is default search by field you can use `->find($id)` to get `$user` from repository

Comment: This won't do (at least not with Symfony 6) because findBy returns an array whereas remove expects an object. You will get: EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.

Comment: @JuergenSchulze yes, you are right. It was a typo. I meant `findOneBy()`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem on my own.
It appears that the delete function requires an argument about what to delete. In my original question it would have deleted the whole database if it would have actually worked.

```
$query = $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('du')
        ->delete('LottolandBundle:User','du')
        ->where('du.id = :id')
        ->setParameter("id", $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

return $query;
```